# Spacy Document Vectors with Custom Number of Dimensions

Tags: spacy

This question may be a duplicate, but I could not find the answer on StackOverflow.

Is there a way to generate document vectors with another number of dimensions such as 25 instead of 300? I also checked the spacy documentation but could not find the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: The resize method gave an error: dictionary changed size during iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document and word vectors in spaCy are not generated by spaCy, they're actually the pre-trained embeddings built off of a large corpus. For more details on the embeddings you can check [Word Vectors and Semantic Similarity](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity) in the docs.

If you wanted to use your own embeddings that were 25 dimensional, you could [follow the instructions here](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity#custom-loading-other). SpaCy won't train new embeddings for you, for that I'd recommend [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/).